# Set up write permissions for VSFTPD user

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I have a raspberry pi microcontroller with VSFTPD running on it, I am trying to write files to it but keep getting permission denied errors. I have the vsftpd.conf file setup correctly I have:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES 
write_enable=YES
```

Basically I need to be able to create folders and files also modify them when I need to. I have the file permissions set as 644 and folders as 755. I was told that for web files and folders this is the correct way of storing the files. Is there a way I can make my ftp(local user) able to write and modify files like root would be able to?

Comment: Are you trying to log in from LAN or from the Internet?

Comment: I am connecting through LAN